# Sync Global AddressList from exchange with personal contacts in exchange via powershell and Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, outlook, exchange-server, azure-runbook

I have a script that accesses ExchangeOnline in an Azure Runbook, first of all I try to access the GAL with `Get-GlobalAddressList` which gives me an error

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-GlobalAddressList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

So therefore I checked the organizations GAL and noticed that I also receive it by just doing `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited` but now I do not know how I can import this into a personals user contacts folder? I dont find any command for doing this, my only idea would be to export the relevant information from the Mailbox command as a CSV, and then import the CSV into the personal users contacts, but is that possible in an Azure runbook?